# Symfony 2 BlueImp OneupUploaderBundle sql error PostPersistEvent not working

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, symfony, oneupuploaderbundle

I'm tryimg to build an Eventlistener so that when entity is created path(url) of the images are persisted to Database. I'm using Blueimp (jQuery-File-Uploader).
But i'm getting an sql exception. I'm guessing that something isn't linked to my listener.

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO Image (name, url) VALUES (?, ?)' with params ["dasdasdas", null]
```

My config.yml

```
oneup_uploader:
mappings:
    gallery:
        frontend: blueimp
```

My service.yml

```
services:
app.bundle.upload_listener:
    class: AppBundle\Eventlistener\ImageuploadListener
    arguments: ["doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
    tags:
        -  { name: kernel.event_listener,  event: oneup_uploader.post_persist, mehtod: onPostUpload}
```

My image Entity

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;    
/**
 * Image
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Image
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="url", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $url;


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set name
 *
 * @param string $name
 * @return Image
 */
public function setName($name)
{
    $this->name = $name;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get name
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}

/**
 * Set url
 *
 * @param string $url
 * @return Image
 */
public function setUrl($url)
{
    $this->url = $url;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get url
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getUrl()
{
    return $this->url;
}
}
```

My imageuploadListener

```
namespace AppBundle\Eventlistener;

use AppBundle\Entity\Image;
use Oneup\UploaderBundle\Event\PostPersistEvent;

class ImageuploadListener
{
protected $manager;

public function __construct(\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $manager)
{
 $this->manager = $manager;

}

public function onPostUpload(PostPersistEvent $event)
{   

    $file = $event->getFile();

    $object = new Image();
    $object->setUrl($file->getPathName());

    $this->manager->persist($object);
    $this->manager->flush();
}

}
```

I'm getting an jquery 500 error, but the images are moved to a folder. The permissions are OK(**all access**).

```
POST http://localhost:8000/_uploader/gallery/upload 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

EDIT: I found this in my error log:

```
 [2015-04-03 11:23:23] event.INFO: An exception was thrown while getting the uncalled listeners (Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to AppBundle\Eventlistener\ImageuploadListener::__construct() must be an instance of AppBundle\Eventlistener\EntityManager, array given, called in D:\x...\app\cache\dev\appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 359 and defined) {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\ContextErrorException(code: 0): Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to AppBundle\\Eventlistener\\ImageuploadListener::__construct() must be an instance of AppBundle\\Eventlistener\\EntityManager, array given, called in D:\\....\\app\\cache\\dev\\appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 359 and defined at D:\\...\\src\\AppBundle\\Eventlistener\\ImageuploadListener.php:12)"} []
```

EDIT 2: I have changed my EntityManager to \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager  And now i'm getting a different error(dev.log):

```
 request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException: "Warning: call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'AppBundle\Eventlistener\ImageuploadListener' does not have a method 'onOneupuploaderPostpersist'" at D:\...\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener.php line 61
```

Any Idea why? Can please someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong? Which file is  calling this method onOneupuploaderPostpersist ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your file **service.yml**

```
mehtod: onPostUpload
```

is typo bug, instead of "**mehtod**" you should have "**method**"

this method is probably default method that is called on listener by OneupUploaderBundle if not specified otherwise

Comment: Thanks! But i'm still getting SQL error because I'm flushing img path early and not at post/entity creation.

Comment: @krex what post/entity creation? where it is in code that you are provided? what is exact error message?. I think you should set setName when creating new Image object. But other than that I do not see other issues in this code.

Comment: The code as it is, is OK. I have created a CRUD for this entity. I wanted to persist img url till I "post" the image entity via crud, soo enter a name, select a img and click post. But this code flushes the url to early and does not persist url value till the image entity is created. Is it possible to persist value/values(urls of the image) till the image entity is posted? 
Its a SQL exception:
 An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO Image (name, url) VALUES (?, ?)' with params ["dsadasd", null]:
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'url' cannot be null

Comment: @krex I dont see any part of code that sets name, but to my understanding is  that you have this event listener that creates image, and some other form which set's name. The problem is that upload happens before submit of form. And Upload even listener event is independent of form submit event. You must manually handle this by for example returning via one up listener created Image ID. Receiving it via javascript, and then passing it to your form with name as hidden field (you must secure it with unique token). And handling it in controller. You can also use sessions for storing this image Id.